# How to get all diffrences from 2 arrays with duplicated values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a project that allows each user to edit a part of a sentence.

let's say our user received original sentence (original) and decided to edit it to another (bluff).

```
  let original = "The sun is clear.the sun is yellow"
  let bluff = "The sun is very bad. the sun is white"
```

the returened output by runing this code (with the help of @henser) is:

```
    let original = "The sun is clear.the sun is yellow".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let bluff = "The sun is very bad. the sun is white".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let words = [];

bluff.forEach((word, index) => {
  words.push({
   text: word,
   index,
   isBluff: words.some(value => value['text'] === word) || !original.includes(word)
  });
});
```

is:

```
0: {text: "The", index: 0, isBluff: false}
1: {text: "sun", index: 1, isBluff: false}
2: {text: "is", index: 2, isBluff: false}
3: {text: "very", index: 3, isBluff: true}
4: {text: "bad.", index: 4, isBluff: true}
5: {text: "the", index: 5, isBluff: true}
6: {text: "sun", index: 6, isBluff: true}
7: {text: "is", index: 7, isBluff: true}
8: {text: "white", index: 8, isBluff: true}
```

the desired output is that the elements from  index 5 untill index 7 (the second "the sun is") is **not** bluff. **it didnt changed!**

it should be:

```
0: {text: "The", index: 0, isBluff: false}
1: {text: "sun", index: 1, isBluff: false}
2: {text: "is", index: 2, isBluff: false}
3: {text: "very", index: 3, isBluff: true}
4: {text: "bad.", index: 4, isBluff: true}
5: {text: "the", index: 5, isBluff: false}
6: {text: "sun", index: 6, isBluff: false}
7: {text: "is", index: 7, isBluff: false}
8: {text: "white", index: 8, isBluff: true}
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emiltayeb912/pua3fqso/88/)

The main goal is to get all the changed from the original sentence, but with the possibility of the duplicated values as you can clearly see.

can you help me achive this? thank you very much

Comment: thank you for that comment. i added on line 27 in https://jsfiddle.net/emiltayeb912/tc9u7pzw/2/ the desired output as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to your ultimate best scenario it seems you're looking to achieve something like this. Is this what you're aiming for?

```js
let original = "The sun is yellow".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let bluff = "The sun is orange and the sun is big".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let words = [];

bluff.forEach((word, index) => {
  words.push({
   text: word,
   isBluff: words.some(value => value['text'] === word) || !original.includes(word)
  });
});

console.log(words);
```

Comment: Your comment worked **almost** perfect
as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emiltayeb912/pua3fqso/22/) .
 Duplicated values aren't marked as bluff, but they should be by my logic since they differ from the original array!
However, it was very close. I intend to continue with your vision.

Comment: so the position of each word in the array is relevant to you? if original sentence is "I like turtles" and bluff is "turtles I like", they should all be marked with isBluff true?

Comment: Yes. i am sorry for not pointing that out. every edit need to be marked. even if its only a change by location. updated my qustion that show that duplacited values and location should be noted.

Comment: then you need to work with the index property. Edited my answer .. test it out ;)

Comment: i think for this comment will probebly make you want to kill me. 
what i meant by the location change, is that if its the same value i dont mind. for example

original - ["a","b","c"]  bluff = ["a","a" , "b","c"] dont need to genrate 
```[{
  isBluff: false,
  text: "a"
}, {
  isBluff: true,
  text: "a"
}, {
  isBluff: true,
  text: "b"
}, {
  isBluff: true,
  text: "c"
}]```

but

```[{
  isBluff: false,
  text: "a"
}, {
  isBluff: true,
  text: "a"
}, {
  isBluff: false,
  text: "b"
}, {
  isBluff: false,
  text: "c"
}]```
i apologize for not being clear.

Comment: I guess the trick with this is to understand the requirements really ':D Edited my answer ... have another try ;)

Comment: we're definitely making progress!

```let original = "The sun is clear. the sun yellow".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let bluff = "The sun is bad. the sun and the sun is white".split(" ").filter(w => w.length > 0);
let words = [];

bluff.forEach((word, index) => {
  words.push({
   text: word,
   isBluff: words.some(value => value['text'] === word) || !original.includes(word)
  });
});

console.log(words);
```
return that the sun at index 6 is false, alltought it is not changed ot move. 
beside that everthihng is perfect.you are so close! really you are helping me alot

Comment: updated my answer to refeect the last steps we've reached. i feel were on the way!